# "User xxx does not have required permissions" in Custom Authentication of SQL Server Reporting Service

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am a new in reporting server and have a problem on Custom/Forms Authentication on the Report Server.

My working environment is: "SQL Server 2012" running on "Windows Server 2008"

I configure my "Form Authentication" step by step follow the tutorial in http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/110547

The sample code I use is downloaded from 
http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2012!Security%20Extension%20Sample&referringTitle=Home

Then I restart my reporting server and visit Report Manager via "myservername/reports" and create a new user xxx, then I want to logon Report Manager as user 'xxx'. But just get eror

"
SQL Server Reporting Services

Error

User '' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.
"

Then I search many relevant topics about this issue and also turn of the Windows User Account Control (UAC). But the problem still exists. 
Is there anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this MS connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/622737/user-does-not-have-required-permissions-verify-that-sufficient-permissions-have-been-granted-and-windows-user-account-control-uac-restrictions-have-been-addressed) issue for some workarounds. The best option is to use IE 8 or later in quirks mode (compatibility view) and to run it as administrator if necessary. Make sure the security is set correctly (accounts and roles) - from Site Settings in top right.
In one example, I could view reports from IE but not FireFox or Chrome (but could configure security) which was obviously UAC related. Fired Chrome as admin, provided credentials (Win account) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In RSReportServer.config file locate the UserName tag and replace the <UserName>username</UserName>
with the user - 'xxx' created - <UserName>xxx</UserName>